# Equality for Normalizer and Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

**Lemma:** $G$ is a finite group, $p$ a prime number with $|G|=p^lm$ with $l\geq 1 and p\nmid m$. Let $s$ denote the amount of sylow groups, then $s|m$.

**Proof**: Is once more pretty straight forward. Let $M=(S_1,S_2,...,S_s)$ be the set of all sylow-groups of G. Because of the second Sylow-theorem the conjugation-operation
$$
G\times M \rightarrow M\, , (a,S)\mapsto aSa^{-1}
$$
which is transitive and also for the orbit $G(S)$ of $S$ it holds that $G(S)=M$ for all $S\in M$ so that $G(S_1)=G(S_2)...=G(S_s)$ so basicly we only have one representation of the orbits. With the orbit-equality we get
$$
s:=|M|=|G(S)|=|G:\text{Sta}_G(S)|
$$
with $\text{Sta}_G(S)$ denoting the stabilizer. Now because the Stabilizer is a Centralizer/Normalizer under conjugation, we get
$$
S \lhd \text{Sta}_G(S)=\text{Nor}_G(S)<G
$$
and with Lagrange
$$
m=|G:S|=|G:\text{Nor}_G(S)||\text{Nor}_G(S):S|=s \cdot |\text{Nor}_G(S):S|
$$

What I don't understand is why we can write
$$
|G:S|=|G:\text{Nor}_G(S)||\text{Nor}_G(S):S|
$$
Any ideas?

Comment: If $H \lt K \lt G$, then the large index is the product of the two smaller ones: $|G:H|=|G:K| \cdot |K:H|$. See for example: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Index_is_multiplicative. I do not see your point provding a proof of the Lemma ....